# Broadcast messages to specific connected users using SignalR hub

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

My goal is when an insert/update happens to the database to immediately notify connected users.

I have a `Hub`.

```
[Authorize]
public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IWorker _worker;

    public NotificationsHub() : this(new WorkerFacade(new ExtremeDataRepository())) { }

    public NotificationsHub(IWorker worker)
    {
        _worker = worker;
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        if (!HubUsersManager.ConnectedUsers.Any(p => p.Name.Equals(Context.User.Identity.Name)))
        {
            HubUsersManager.ConnectedUsers.Add(new HubUserHandler
            {
                Name = Context.User.Identity.Name,
                ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId
            });
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    //public override Task OnDisconnected()
    //{
    //    HubUserHandler hubUserHandler =
    //        HubUsersManager.ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == Context.User.Identity.Name);

    //    if (hubUserHandler != null)
    //        HubUsersManager.ConnectedUsers.Remove(hubUserHandler);

    //    return base.OnDisconnected();
    //}

    public async Task<ICollection<NotificationMessage>> GetAllPendingNotifications(string userId)
    {
        return await _worker.GetAllPendingNotifications(userId);
    }

    public void UpdateNotificationMessagesToAllClients(ICollection<NotificationMessage> notificationMessages)
    {
        Clients.All.updateNotificationMessages(notificationMessages);
    }
}
```

As you can see I removed the OnDisconnected from the manual mapping of connected users, to have the username and the ConnectionId to use later for my Entity Framework MemberShip users to broadcast messages, because the OnDisconnected is invoked everytime a client goes away of the hub and not when actually disconnects, e.g. close the browser.

The initialization of SignalR works perfect and I tested it, `GetAllPendingNotifications` is called upon connection start and I invoke the function of the SignalR Javascript code, see below the code.

```
// A simple templating method for replacing placeholders enclosed in curly braces.
if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = o[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}

if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
        return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    };
}

$(function () {

    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
    var notificationsHub = $.connection.notificationsHub;
    var userName, userId;

    // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
    notificationsHub.client.updateNotificationMessages = updateNotificationsToPage;

    function updateNotificationsToPage(notificationMessages) {
        alert('Im in updating notifications');
        if (notificationMessages.count > 0) {
            $.each(function(index) {
                alert($(this).Message);
            });
        }
    };

    function init() {
        notificationsHub.server.getAllPendingNotifications(userId).done(updateNotificationsToPage);
    }

    function userDetailsRetrieved(data) {
        userName = data.UserName;
        userId = data.Id;
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(init);
    }

    function getUserDetails() {
        var baseURL = document.baseURI,
            url;
        if (!baseURL.endsWith('Home/GetUserDetails')) {
            if (baseURL.endsWith('/'))
                url = baseURL + 'Home/GetUserDetails';
            else if (baseURL.endsWith('/Home') ||
                baseURL.endsWith('/Home/'))
                url = baseURL + '/GetUserDetails';
            else {
                url = baseURL + '/Home/GetUserDetails';
            }
        } else
            url = baseURL;

        $.ajax({
            url: url, success: userDetailsRetrieved, type: 'POST', error: function () {
            console.log(arguments);
        }, dataType: 'json' });
    }

    getUserDetails();
});
```

I know that mapping might be not necessary, and I can override the implementation to map it to my actual `ApplicationUser` GUID Id to avoid it, but for now it seems to serve the purpose, might change it if I first make it work.

You also can see the `IWorker` reference that I use to get some data if a client invokes a server method.
Additionally the `IWorker` concrete implementation is being used by all the `Controllers` and has a property `Clients` so I can broadcast messages back to connected clients immediately.

```
private IHubConnectionContext _clients;
private IHubConnectionContext Clients
{
    get {
        return _clients ?? (_clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>().Clients);
    }
}
```

Which is populated properly.
And in some point of the application the `IWorker` is invoking the `Clients` property.

```
foreach (HubUserHandler hubUserHandler in HubUsersManager.ConnectedUsers)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await GetApplicationUserWithName(hubUserHandler.Name);
            List<string> userRoles = await GetUserRoles(user);
            bool isInRole = userRoles.Any(p => p.Equals("ARole"));

            List<NotificationMessage> testList = new List<NotificationMessage>
            {
                new NotificationMessage {Message = "TEST MESSAGE!"}
            };

            if (isInRole)
                Clients.Client(hubUserHandler.ConnectionId).updateNotificationMessages(testList);
        }
```

Nothing comes to my browser, two alerts should popup, one saying `Im in updating notifications` and one `TEST MESSAGE` like you see in the `Javascript` code above.

**[EDIT]**

Changed code to send message to specific `Group` but nothing again shows up to my client browser.

```
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            if (_groupManager.Count == 0)
            {
                ICollection<string> rolesCollection = _worker.GetAllRoles();
                foreach (string roleName in rolesCollection)
                {
                    _groupManager.Add(roleName);
                }
            }

            foreach (string groupRole in _groupManager.Groups)
            {
                if (Context.User.IsInRole(groupRole))
                {
                    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupRole);
                }
            }

            return base.OnConnected();
        }
```

Somewhere in my worker class:

```
    List<NotificationMessage> testList = new List<NotificationMessage>
        {
            new NotificationMessage {Message = "TEST MESSAGE!"}
        };

    Clients.Group("TestGroup").updateNotificationMessages(testList);
```

I guess I miss something!!!

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents: did you have a look into the `Clients.User()` method? It already does all the `ConnectionId` mapping for you, and you are using `Context.User` so it should work out of the box. If you need something more complex you can write you own mapping logic inside a custom implementation of `IUserIdProvider`. At least you would remove one level of complexity (but not sure it would solve your specific issue if the problem is not because of that). Just an idea.

Comment: Yes, I will move the logic to the IUserIdProvider, it seems better since I use ASP.NET Authentication. I will try the Clients.User() empty overload.

Comment: The Clients.User() doesn't make sense to my problem because I might have more than one users connected need to receive the same message.

Comment: Well, I don't see how that would be different compared to your approach with ConnectionId. Instead of looping through connection ids, which is 'unsafe', you would loop through user ids, which is one problem less to solve. Also, I would suggest you to see if you can find a way to group users in some way (for example using roles) and leverage Groups support from SignalR, this way you can hit all of them at the same time with just one call. Maybe you can review your logic in that direction.

Comment: Yes I agree to your comment, i will delete current logic and build new one trying with Groups and ConnectionId from the Hub. Is there a way to get all currently connected to the hub Clients ConnectionIds? I understand the IUserIdProvider will let me map ConnectionId with User.Identity id from my database. Of course with Groups I will have to just say send message to Group and all connected clients to the group theoretically will be notified!

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to get all current ConnectionIds, but still, even it was possible that would not be the recommended way to do it. The less you mess with ConnectionId, the better, and in general it's quite often possible to restructure your code to solve a problem without using them. Groups are really great for that.

Comment: Let me do this refactor in the afternoon and get back with hopefully great result!

Comment: I have edited the question, no results again when changing to use Groups to send the message.

Comment: This is too much code to digest, at least for me :) I can't see anything outstanding. No JavaScript errors? If you put server side breakpoints, do you see them hit as expected? If the answer is yes to both, I'd suggest you to start a sample from scratch, make it work with a 'hello world' call as in any SignalR tutorial, and then work towards your solution with baby step, each time checking that things are still working.

Comment: Yes to both, no Javascript errors, the breakpoint in the server hits properly, just no alert is shown in the client. I implemented Groups and single group for user, nothing happens! Guess I will go with the chat like scenario with the client asking from server between time intervals in Javascript and using SignalR.